# As well as meaning hollow or superficial, can "hueco" also mean proud?

Tags: traducción, significado, definiciones

I came across the Apple English-Spanish dictionary definition for "hueco" today and thought "how interesting, there is a semantic link in Spanish between hollowness and pride". Then I became curious and searched in other online dictionaries and found that none of them listed the second meaning of "hueco" as pride. The Apple dictionary does specify that it's only in Iberian Spanish, but I can't find anything else about this online.

**Update**

Here is a screenshot of the entry as people have asked for it. I'm aware that the in context example of the word is wrong though.

[image]

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to provide a link to the source, but can you copy the dictionary entry? Maybe that would help us. I have never heard "hueco" meaning "pride".

Comment: This would sure be a colloquial use of the term.  I imagine if the dictionary says it is so.  The example doesn't sound so strange to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the dictionary of the language ([DLE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_la_lengua_espa%C3%B1ola) de sus siglas en castellano) [hueco](https://dle.rae.es/hueco?m=form) includes among other defintions

> 5. adj. Presumido, hinchado, vano.

and if we look at [presumido](https://dle.rae.es/presumido?m=form) we see

> 1. adj. Vano, jactancioso, orgulloso, que tiene alto concepto de sí mismo. U. t. c. s.

which does seem to suggest that hueco could be interpreted as proud (but not pride since the 5th definition for hueco is purely as an adjective not a substantive).

Comment: "THE dictionary of THE language"?!

Comment: @aparente001 it was an attempt to translate its Spanish title which no longer seems to contain the phrase "Royal Academy". The links should clarify which dictionary is intended though.

Comment: @aparente001, it looks like lost in translation: the RAE (Real Academia Española) dictionary is known as the "Diccionario de la lengua".

Comment: @Chococroc - Thanks, I understand better now.  All I know is that it came out pretty strange in the post -- it looks as though the author feels that there is only one Spanish dictionary worthy of the name "dictionary of the Spanish language."  Personally I find the DRAE helpful most of the time but not *every time*.

Comment: @aparente001 no problem, I will be more explicit next time, it was over-terse. One of my bosses said I had a problem with brevity.

Comment: @mdewey - I have no opinion about what you did at work.  My older son used to lose points on his writing in school because he was a minimalist.  Then came the Common Core and son #2 who was also a minimalist did great, because he *answered the question precisely* (give the evidence that's in the text for such-and-so inference).  I myself admire succinctness and aspire to it.  But I'll explain why this bothered me.  I had a classmate from (unnamed South American country so as not to offend anyone) who was arrogant about his country's Spanish being the only true Spanish.  How about a tiny edit?

Comment: @mdewey it was quite clear to me what you meant by the dictionary of the language thanks to the accompanying link. I don't think that the comments you've received from the other user are in any way helpful, but I'm unsurprised to see people being anally retentive on the internet.